# What is the animation duration of UIPageViewController's setViewControllers method

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I was wondering how one could get the animation duration of this method:

```
setViewControllers(_ viewControllers: [UIViewController]?, 
              direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection, 
               animated: Bool, 
             completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)
```

When the `animated` parameter is set to `true`.

Comment: By starting noting time before executing method and noting time after completion handler is called, we can solve this right. Are you looking for something else?

Comment: I was just wondering if it was possible to access this value somewhere, without calculating it

Comment: You can check my edited answer now. I came across this property named `UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator` in documentation and tried it. It worked.

Comment: Why do you need to know this? If you want to something after the animation ends, you've got the completion handler right there, so what's the _real_ problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I want to trigger another animation at the same time and I want this animation to last as long as the one I'm talking about in my question.

Comment: @Randy Did you solved this? Found the duration? It's killing us ah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following code should do the work. Please let me know if there is any other way

**Method 1:**

```
let initialTime:CFAbsoluteTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

let pager:UIPageViewController = UIPageViewController()
pager.setViewControllers(nil, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: true, completion: {(success) -> Void in
   let animationTime: CFTimeInterval = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - initialTime
   print(animationTime)
})
```

**Method 2:**

```
let pager:UIPageViewController = UIPageViewController()
pager.setViewControllers(nil, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: true, completion: {(success) -> Void in
   if let transiton = pager.transitionCoordinator {
      print(transiton.transitionDuration)
   }
})
```

**Edit:**

As [rickster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/957768/rickster) mentions in the comment and according to official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontrollertransitioncoordinatorcontext/1619286-transitionduration), `Method 2` is the preferred method as it is a built in API which gives accurate time for animation to finish if animations proceeds without any userinteraction.

Comment: Transition coordinators are the preferred method here. The transition duration is private and subject to change — for all we know there could be a future iOS release in which the duration for this particular animation is not only different from the one time you measured it, but variable so that it's not the same duration every time. Transition coordinators, on the other hand, automatically work with the system animation, following not just its duration but its timing curves, too.

Comment: Hey there. The value of the transitionDuration is nil. I need to access it before the animation starts. Is it possible?

Comment: May I know the reason for which you need to access it before the animation starts?

Comment: @KrishnaCA Yes, I want to sync the pageVc transition animation with external UIView animation.. Do you know how can I get it before?